Is it correct to say "curriculum of study"?
Dictionaries give the following meaning for the word "curriculum":
"the aggregate of courses of study given in a school, college, university, etc."
So, why would someone say "curriculum of study" instead of just "curriculum"? Does not both mean the same thing?
Edit:
I was asked where did I encounter such a phrase. It is from the English Course book "Learn to read science". There was the following example sentence:
At the university students are offered a curriculum of study which is followed by a test and the award of a degree.

Where did you encounter "curriculum of study"?

People often add superfluous words. The goal of language use isn't to utter the fewest words possible; there is redundancy even in your question.

Is going to an ATM machine so bad? Does the IRS provide a service after taking your revenue internally?

"curriculum" is also used to refer to the content of a specific class. So someone might add "of study" to make it clear that they're talking about the aggregate sense .

Curriculum has other uses, so, when he context does not make that clear, it may be necessary to specify what the curriculum is of.

This question can't have a reasonable answer without giving more context. Please use the "Edit" button to show more about the usage you found.

After the edit, your question is clear enough, but the comments posted so far probably provide enough of an answer to it: yes, of study is, strictly speaking redundant in this context (although there may be some contexts in which it is not), but that redundancy is harmless, and of the kind that is quite common in normal communication. Posting that as a formal answer is probably unnecessary.
